# CountDownTimer being executed multiple times even after a check

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer in a service, that get's started after a check

```
if (timerToNextDay == null) {
        timeToNextDay(some long here);
}
```

the problem is, everytime the service is being initialized and this timer is being checked, it always returns null, even though I am not canceling it anywhere. So after a few starts of the service the timer is being initialized 3 times, I can notice that from this log in its onTick method

```
Log.i("Hours to next day ", (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60) / 60) + "");
```

So what can I do to check if the timer is running, to not start it multiple times?

Comment: Show more code .where do you put this check for the timer

Comment: inside onStartCommand in the Service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent from timer being initialized multiple times, It has to be `static`, so it should be declared like this

> private static CountDownTimer timer;

this ensures that there won't be multiple instances of the `CountDownTimer`